# impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Failed after retrying 3 times

Tags: python-3.x, hive, impyla, ibis

I use impyla and ibis to connect hive server, but I got the error.
I tried the following code:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
impcur = connect(host="kudu3", port=10000, database="yingda_test", password=None, user='admin', kerberos_service_name='None').cursor()
```

The new error came out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edy/src/PythonProjects/dt-center-algorithm/test/1.py", line 4, in <module>
    impcur = connect(host="kudu3", port=10000, database="yingda_test", password=None, user='admin', kerberos_service_name='None').cursor()
  File "/usr/local/conda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 129, in cursor
    session = self.service.open_session(user, configuration)
  File "/usr/local/conda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1187, in open_session
    resp = self._rpc('OpenSession', req, True)
  File "/usr/local/conda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1080, in _rpc
    response = self._execute(func_name, request, retry_on_http_error)
  File "/usr/local/conda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1142, in _execute
    .format(self.retries))
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Failed after retrying 3 times
```

thrift                    0.15.0
thrift-sasl               0.4.3
thriftpy2                 0.4.14
pure-sasl                 0.6.2
sasl                      0.2.1
thrift-sasl               0.4.3
ibis-framework            2.0.0
impyla                    0.17.0
python version: 3.7.12 with anaconda

And I have tried ibis-1.3.0 and 2.0 version. Can u guys give some advices? tks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem.

My code is:

```py
from impala.dbapi import connect
import psycopg2

conn_hive = connect(host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", port=xxx, user='admin', 
                    password='password', database='xxx', auth_mechanism="PLAIN", timeout=6000)
hive_cursor = conn_hive.cursor()
hive_cursor.execute(query_sql)
data_list = hive_cursor.fetchall()
...get data...
hive_cursor.close()
conn_hive.close()
```

After my colleagues and I tried, we find it will be successful when we **reconnect hive manually**.

It means if you want to get different data from the same hive database, you had better close the connection and reconnect hive manually by the following codes:

```py
conn_hive = connect(host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", port=xxx, user='admin', 
                    password='password', database='xxx', auth_mechanism="PLAIN", timeout=6000)
hive_cursor = conn_hive.cursor()
hive_cursor.execute(query_sql)
data_list = hive_cursor.fetchall()
...get data1...
hive_cursor.close()
conn_hive.close()

conn_hive = connect(host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", port=xxx, user='admin', 
                    password='password', database='xxx', auth_mechanism="PLAIN", timeout=6000)
hive_cursor = conn_hive.cursor()
hive_cursor.execute(query_sql)
data_list = hive_cursor.fetchall()
...get data2...
hive_cursor.close()
conn_hive.close()
```

Finally, my colleagues told me that there was a problem with impala recently.